# Pausing of the terminal process in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line

I was thinking if there was anyway so that we can pause the installation or downloading of any software from the terminal.Means if the terminal processes can be paused and resumed??
I asked because suppose I am downloading something from download manager and also a file from the terminal and I am not getting enough speed from the download manager due to this.So is there any way that the terminal process could be paused??
This question is different because i want to know what will happen if I pause a file which I was downloading fro the terminal and file download takes place through internet.I am not asking if I suspend an ongoing process like the running of a program which is internal to the computer.

Comment: @Jacob..This question is different because i want to know what will happen if I pause a file which I was downloading fro the terminal and file download takes place through internet.I am not asking if I suspend an ongoing process like the running of a program which is internal to the computer.

Comment: There is no difference at all, assuming the link is still available of course. Just try it and you'll see.

Comment: OK..so you are saying that we can pause the download of file thorugh Ctrl+Z..thanks and I will surely try it bro..:)

Comment: I tried to be sure; works here. just type `%` + Return like in the linked dupe and it resumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes, there are way to stop processes. Simplest - use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> shortcut while process is running. The way it works can be read in `bash`'s manual:

> Typing the suspend character (typ‐
>          ically ^Z, Control-Z) while a process is running causes that process to
>          be stopped and returns control to bash.   Typing  the  delayed  suspend
>          character  (typically  ^Y,  Control-Y) causes the process to be stopped
>          when it attempts to read input from the terminal,  and  control  to  be
>          returned  to bash.  The user may then manipulate the state of this job,
>          using the bg command to continue it in the background, the  fg  command
>          to continue it in the foreground, or the kill command to kill it.  A ^Z
>          takes effect immediately, and has the additional side effect of causing
>          pending output and typeahead to be discarded

However, considering that update is more important than downloading file, I wouldn't recommend pausing the update/upgrade process; pause the file download first, resume later. Or avoid mixing both

Comment: @Serg..I was asking if it was possible to pause the download of file from terminal taking place from Internet(which I am unsure of how to pause and resume)..I am not asking of stopping of the processes of the running of a program or that type of stuff..Did you get my point?